# Python using dictionary for multiple RegEX re.sub

Tags: regex, python-3.x, replace

I am trying to manipulate a text from SNMP sysDescr.0 output with Python 3, I need to use a dictionary that contains the patterns and their replacements as follows:

```
myDict = {
    r' \(\/sw.+': '',
    r' \(\/ws.+$': '',
    r'Compiled on.{36}': '',
    r'Ruckus Wireless, Inc. ': '',
    r'Brocade Communications Systems, Inc. ': '',
    r' Switch': '',
    r', ROM': ' - ROM',
    r' revision': 'revision',
    r' IronWare': 'IronWare'
}
```

I found belowcode here but the first three patterns in the dictionary are not working, while the rest are OK, I don't know why:

```
def multiple_replace(myDict, text):
    regex = re.compile(r'(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, myDict.keys())))
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: myDict.get(mo.group(), mo.group()),text)
```

How can I modify the above function to be able to correctly run RegEX for the first three patterns? I tried most similar solutions here but non of them was able to handle the first three patterns.

My simple version is below, but I am really interested to see how the first solution should be modified to work correctly as I am new to python anyway:

```
def multiple_replace(myDict, text):
    for key, val in myDict.items():
        if re.search(key, text):
            text = re.sub(key, val, text)
    return text
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
HP J9856A 2530-24G-2SFP+ Switch, revision YA.16.05.0004, ROM YA.15.20 (/ws/swbuildm/rel_venice_qaoff/code/build/lakes(swbuildm_rel_venice_qaoff_rel_venice)) (Formerly ProCurve),.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.166
ProCurve J9088A Switch 2610-48, revision R.11.122, ROM R.10.06 (/sw/code/build/nemo),.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.77
Ruckus Wireless, Inc. ICX7250-48-HPOE, IronWare Version 08.0.70aT211 Compiled on Jan 18 2018 at 04:21:25 labeled as SPS08070a,.1.3.6.1.4.1.1991.1.3.62.2.2.1.1
```

and what I need it to become:

```
HP J9856A 2530-24G-2SFP+,revision YA.16.05.0004 - ROM YA.15.20,.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.166
HP J9088A 2610-48,revision R.11.122 - ROM R.10.06,.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.77
ICX7250-48-HPOE,IronWare Version 08.0.70aT211 SPS08070a,.1.3.6.1.4.1.1991.1.3.62.2.2.1.1
```

Honestly I have no idea which is better or faster, your input is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: You are mixing regex and literal patterns. `map(re.escape, myDict.keys())` escapes the strings, and corrupts the regex patterns.

Comment: thank you, how should the function become then? should I remove re.escape?

Comment: No, make sure you make your keys are all regexps. However, it looks like your first regexps do not do what you expect them to do. You must try `r' \(\/sw.+\)'` and `r' \(\/ws.+\)'`. See https://ideone.com/iXaHBt

Comment: thank you very much, but I did not to do that with the 2nd solution. Also note that it needs modification to work as  follows: def multiple_replaec(mydict, text):
    for rx, repl in mydict.items():
        if re.search(rx, text):
            text = re.sub(rx, repl, text)
    return text.strip()

Comment: BTW, adding re.search to the function makes execution faster.

Comment: So, does my approach work for you in general? I do not know the exact rules, you may keep the regexps as is. And: if you have compiled res, you do not need `re.sub(rx, repl, text)`, `rx.sub(repl, text)` is enough.

Comment: yes, it works, thank you very much. First time I tried it, it did not work because of inconsistent indentation of spaces and tabs but I did not pay attention to the error till I tried it few minutes ago.

Comment: I believe you should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure you make your keys are all compiled `re` objects, and once you have your regex-replacement dictionary ready, you will need to iterate over these key-value pairs and perform replacements one by one, with

```
for rx,repl in myDict.items():
        text = rx.sub(repl, text)
```

where `rx` will be the compiled `re` object and `repl` is the replacement string.

Full code snippet:

```
import re
myDict = {
    re.compile(r' \(\/sw.+\)'): '',
    re.compile(r' \(\/ws.+\)'): '',
    re.compile(r'Compiled on.{36}'): '',
    re.compile(re.escape(r'Ruckus Wireless, Inc. ')): '',
    re.compile(re.escape(r'Brocade Communications Systems, Inc. ')): '',
    re.compile(re.escape(r' Switch')): '',
    re.compile(re.escape(r', ROM')): ' - ROM',
    re.compile(re.escape(r' revision')): 'revision',
    re.compile(re.escape(r' IronWare')): 'IronWare'
}
s = """HP J9856A 2530-24G-2SFP+ Switch, revision YA.16.05.0004, ROM YA.15.20 (/ws/swbuildm/rel_venice_qaoff/code/build/lakes(swbuildm_rel_venice_qaoff_rel_venice)) (Formerly ProCurve),.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.166
ProCurve J9088A Switch 2610-48, revision R.11.122, ROM R.10.06 (/sw/code/build/nemo),.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.77
Ruckus Wireless, Inc. ICX7250-48-HPOE, IronWare Version 08.0.70aT211 Compiled on Jan 18 2018 at 04:21:25 labeled as SPS08070a,.1.3.6.1.4.1.1991.1.3.62.2.2.1.1"""

def multiple_replace(myDict, text):
    for rx,repl in myDict.items():
        text = rx.sub(repl, text)
    return text

print(multiple_replace(myDict, s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/iXaHBt).

Output:

```
HP J9856A 2530-24G-2SFP+,revision YA.16.05.0004 - ROM YA.15.20,.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.166
ProCurve J9088A 2610-48,revision R.11.122 - ROM R.10.06,.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.77
ICX7250-48-HPOE,IronWare Version 08.0.70aT211 SPS08070a,.1.3.6.1.4.1.1991.1.3.62.2.2.1.1
```

Comment: Do you need to compile?  Most RE functions are automatically compiled and cached.  Does compiling make it clearer? Does it provide sufficient performance improvement?   
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/625f6704c0d783360574bbab2f78b0b9bbed5891/Lib/re.py#L288

Comment: @PeterCibulskis In this case, when using a lot of regexps against lots of strings, compiled patterns are more efficient.